# Record and send voice

Tags: java, android, telegram, voice

im a new programmer android and i want make an app that users can record the voice and send that then the voice save on my host. for example in Telegram app you can record voice and send that.what shall i do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3):

**As you said that you are a beginner you have to do small projects like making calculator, small blog based app or i do not know parsing JSON , try google maps play with XMLs.
nobody will send you the source code of the app that you need it includes a lot of minor staff that you have to learn step by step..**
Best regards.